# Cocos-2dx v3 centering background sprite problems

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Here is my background image:

[image]

And here is some code that I would assume scales this image to fully fit the screen.

```
Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
auto bg = Sprite::create("grad.png");
bg->setScale(visibleSize.width / bg->getContentSize().width, visibleSize.height / bg->getContentSize().height);
bg->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));
addChild(bg);
```

I would expect those 4 lines to create a background sprite that would cover the entire screen size. However, here's a screenshot of what I am actually getting on my iPhone6+:

[image: Image isn't centered]

If I change the first line to

```
Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
```

Then this is what I get, which isn't quite right either:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `VisibleSize` is correct, you just need one more change:

```
bg->setPosition(director->getVisibleOrigin());
```

By default, cocos2d-x uses [ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support#No-border), so the bottom part of winSize is likely to be cropped.
`getVisibleSize()` returns the visible origin in **Point** rather then pixel.

Comment: What's the difference to what he's using right now? Why does your answer work better? It's really just a random suggestion, until you create some context and explain things.

Comment: Thanks, looks better.